# How to make drag drop stay at dropped place after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop, local-storage

Can someone please help me!

I am working on assignment with drag & drop and localstorage.
This is my first time writing a code involving localstorage. I'm creating
someting like kanban board.

The problem I am having right now is, I have no idea how am i going
to make all cards in the board stay at where i drop it after page refresh.

Here is what i've tried so far

```js
const todos = document.querySelectorAll(".todo");
const all_status = document.querySelectorAll(".box")


todos.forEach((todo) => {
  todo.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  todo.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
});

function dragStart() {
  draggableTodo = this;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.style.display = "none";

  }, 0);
  console.log("dragStart");
}

function dragEnd() {
  draggableTodo = null;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.style.display = "block";

  }, 0);
  console.log("dragEnd");
}

all_status.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
  box.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
  box.addEventListener("draleave", dragLeave);
  box.addEventListener("drop", dragDrop);
});

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //console.log("dragOver");
}

function dragEnter() {
  console.log("dragEnter");
}

function dragLeave() {
  console.log("dragLeave");
}

function dragDrop() {
  this.appendChild(draggableTodo);
  var left = this.offsetLeft;
  var top = this.offsetTop;
  localStorage.setItem("left", left);
  localStorage.setItem("top", top);
  console.log("dropped");
}
```

Can check on my JSFiddle too

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pekja/qtbs1jwn/55/)

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one element which you want to keep it's state, "left" and "top" is fine, but you would try to generate a key which defines the element.

```
localStorage.setItem("elementAPosition", {left: '10px', top: '5px'})
```

And when your scripts run at the first place, you can check element positions and set their place.

```
let elementAPos = localStorage.getItem("elementAPosition") //this returns an object with left and top keys.
elementA.style.left = elementAPos.left
elementA.style.top = elementAPos.top
```

Comment: thank you for answering. If i want all my card to stay after page refresh can, i use this code? my card need to have same id in html part. Am i right?